# Yii2 - Unable to resolve the request "TblHotel/create"

Tags: yii2

I've created Controller, Model and View files in backend

```
backend/
       controller/
                 TblHotelController.php
       models/
             TblHotel.php
             TblHotelSearch.php
       views/
            tbl-hotel
```

These files are untouched.
When I'm calling url site.com/backend/web/TblHotel/create.
It shows not found 404 errors. Unable to resolve the request TblHotel/create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is yii2 then the actual link that you need to use the link site.com/backend/web/tbl-hotel/create

Comment: If i use this link site.com/backend/web/tbl-hotel/create. It shows Unable to find 'backend\controllers\TblHotelController' in file: C:\...backend/controllers/TblHotelController.php. Namespace missing? So I changed the link to site.com/backend/web/tblHotel/create. It shows 404 error, page not found.

Comment: you have a problem with the namespace, the error shows you this. You can try tblHotel/create as many times as you want... that will not work.

Comment: I tried tblHotel/create, but it showing 404 error and also I mentioned that in my comment itself.

Comment: So fix the namespace issue.

Comment: Your tblHotelController.php should start with
`<?php
namespace backend\controllers;`

Comment: Thank you.. now its working.. I changed namespace from app\controllers to backend\controllers. Now its working. May I know where to use app\controller?

Comment: app\controller you can use when you use the simple yii2 template, not the advanced one. Accept the answer if it is working now.